# Replace All Instances of HTML Comments in Database

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I recently imported quite a few posts (many thousands) into WordPress and found out that quite a few of them had images at the start of the post that were commented out
`<!--<img src="" />-->`.

Unfortunately WordPress for whatever reason is adding this comment to all the content, so the content is there but doesn't show up.  So I figured the easy way to solve this was to run a find and replace SQL statement, to find all instances and replace with nothing.

I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work.  I'm no expert with SQL, so I was figuring I could use a wildcard in the find statement but apparently not, or at least I can't figure it out.

So what I want to do is find all occurrences of commented out images and replace them with nothing, basically just delete them.  The images aren't all the same.  Some just have a src, some also have height and width, some have alt attributes, etc.  And they are not all in the same order.  So I was hoping something like `UPDATE wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, '<!--<img %>-->', '')` would work, but it doesn't.

So if anyone has any ideas on how to do this, I'd be grateful for the help.

Comment: What does happen when you run the query? Nothing??

Comment: Says there's an error in the SQL syntax

Comment: `REPLACE` doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: What kind of database is this? Some have better support for regex replace than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). I think your problem is using the '%' without a `LIKE` does not work. The question recommends using a user defined function

Comment: Yeah looks like that question has answers that should get me where I need.  Thanks!